$L_2$ projection of product terms
I asked a question here in regards to the following equality
$$E\left[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid D, X\right] = \frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X)},$$
where $D$ is binary random variable, and $X,A$ are two arbitrary variables.
Now I'm wondering about the following quantities
$$
\frac{D_1}{P\left(D_1=1 \mid D_0=1, L_0,U_0, L_1\right)} \frac{D_0}{P\left(D_0=1 \mid L_0, U_0\right)}\quad (1)
$$
and
$$
\frac{D_1}{P\left(D_1=1 \mid D_0=1,L_0,L_1\right)} \frac{D_0}{P\left(D_0=1 \mid L_0\right)} \quad (2)
$$
I can see that $\frac{D_1}{P\left(D_1=1 \mid D_0=1,L_0,L_1\right)}$ is the projection of $\frac{D_1}{P\left(D_1=1 \mid D_0=1, L_0,U_0, L_1\right)}$ onto $L_0,L_1$; and $\frac{D_0}{P\left(D_0=1 \mid L_0\right)}$ is the projection of $\frac{D_0}{P\left(D_0=1 \mid L_0, U_0\right)}$ onto $L_0$.
But I don't have any intuition about whether there is any meaningful interpretation on the relationship between the product (1) and the product (2).
